# How to group daily data on weekly basis using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to group  the number of hours that employees worked for the last 4 weeks but I want to group them on a weekly basis.  For example:

```
WEEK                    HOURS
Feb 24 to March 2         55
March 3 to March 9        40
March 10 to March 16      48
March 17 to March 23      37
```

This is what I have so far, please help.  thanks

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

    SELECT CAST(MIN( [DT]) AS VARCHAR(20))+' TO '+CAST (MAX([DT]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DATE,
           SUM(HOURS) AS NUM_HRS
    FROM   MyTable
    GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,[DT])
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT[DT])=7
```

Comment: You could try something like `GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DD, DT, '1/1/1900')/7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(DD, 
            CONVERT(INT, (DATEDIFF(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT)/7)) * 7, 
           '1/1/1900') [WeekBeginDate],
    DATEADD(DD,
            (CONVERT(INT, (DATEDIFF(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT)/7)) * 7) + 6,
           '1/1/1900') [WeekEndDate],
    SUM(HOURS) AS NUM_HRS
FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT)/7)
```

Though this is the brute force trick, I think in your case it will work.

**EDIT :** Modified the query a little bit, the error was caused because of the order in which `DATEDIFF` calculates the difference.

Also here is a [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50cca3/8) with a working example.

**EDIT 2 :** Updated the Fiddle with the Date Format. To customize the date format, [**this article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) would help.

Comment: do i need to replace this: '1/1/1900' with some kind of data from my table or keep it like that?  i am getting some weird dates like this: 1785-10-10 00:00:00.000

Comment: @moe I have modified the query and added a fiddle.

Comment: thanks, is there a way not to show the time in the date? i only want to show the date without the zeros.  WeekBeginDate has the DateTime format but would like to show only the date.  thanks

Comment: @moe You could always format the date to whatever format you want. Updated the fiddle with the format.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Calendar auxilliary table, with Year, Month, Week, Date columns (you can also add holidays and other interesting stuff to it, it has many potential uses) and populate it for the period of interest.

After that, it's as easy as this:

```
SELECT sum(hours), cast(min(date) as varchar), cast(max(date) as varchar)
FROM Calendar c
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable h on h.Date = c.date
GROUP BY year, week
ORDER BY year, week
```

Comment: Add a WHERE clause to filter on Calendar table

Comment: @moe `WHERE DATEDIFF(week, c.date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 3`

Answer (score 1):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

    SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,DT) AS WEEK,
           SUM(HOURS) AS NUM_HRS
    FROM   MyTable
    WHERE DT >= DATEADD(WEEK, -4, GetDate()),
    GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,[DT])
```